# Run task for watched file

Tags: task, gruntjs, watch, stylus

Consider following `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var 
        stylusFiles = [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'radio/static/css/',
                src: ['*.styl'],
                ext: ['.css']
            },
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'radio/static/polymer/radio-light/',
                src: ['**/*.styl'],
                ext: ['.css']
            },
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'radio/static/themes/',
                src: ['**/*.styl'],
                ext: ['.css']
            }
        ];

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        stylus: {
            all: {
                files: stylusFiles,
            },
        },

        watch: {
            files: [
                'radio/static/css/*.styl',
                'radio/static/themes/**/*.styl',
                'radio/static/polymer/radio-light/**/*.styl',
            ],
            tasks: ['stylus:all'],
        }
      });


    // Other stuff
};
```

Stylus task compiles every .styl file found in specified folders.
Watch task now leading to recompilation of all .styl files, and I want to recompile only watched ones.
I've read a little bit about watch.event, but I can't understand how to run default task (e.g. `stylus:single`) with watched pathname.
In other words is there a way to implement stylus subtask, which could be run by `grunt.task.run()` with custom files option?

**UPDATED**: The solution is below in my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this particular case is following:

- create watch task, which does not runs any tasks for all target files and spawn set to `false`:

  ```
  grunt.initConfig({
      // ...
      watch: {
          stylus: {
              files: ['whatever/*.styl'],
              options: {
                  spawn: false,
              },
          },
      },
      // ..
  })
  ```

  - listen for watch event:
    `grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath) { /* ... */ });`
  - check action type: if file wasn't deleted recompile it, otherway delete appropriate CSS file

Full code example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
    stylus: {
        compile: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'whatever/',
                    src: ['/stylus/*.styl'],
                    dest: 'css/',
                    ext: '.css',
                    // Compile all files from 'whatever/stylus' and put results
                    // in 'whatever/css/<proper name>.css'
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    watch: {
        stylus: {
            files: ['whatever/*.styl'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            },
        },
    },
    // ..
});

grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath) {
    var
        dst, ext, files;
    dst = filepath.split('.');
    ext = dst.slice(-1);
    if (ext == 'styl') {
        // prepare destination file name,
        // e.g. <dir>/stylus/<name>.styl -> <dir>/css/<name>.css
        dst.splice(-1,1,'css');
        dst = dst.join('.').split('/');
        dst.splice(-2,1,'css');
        dst = dst.join('/');

        if (action != 'deleted') {
            // replace stylus task dynamic patter
            files = {};
            files[dst] = filepath;
            grunt.config('stylus.compile.files', files);
            grunt.task.run('stylus:compile');
        } else {
            // delete obsolete css file
            grunt.file.delete(dst);
            grunt.log.writeln('File "' + dst + '" deleted.');
        }

    }
});
```

Helpful links:

- [grunt-contrib-watch README](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#compiling-files-as-needed)
- [Grunt FAQ: How can I share parameters across multiple tasks?](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#how-can-i-share-parameters-across-multiple-tasks)
- [Grunt FAQ: Globals and configs](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#globals-and-configs)

Hope, this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood was, you could create multiple json objects and assign to variables. So then in your `stylus`create multiple sub tasks as follows. So you can use the same sub tasks for the `watch` as well.

ex.

```
    var stylusStaticFiles = [ {
        expand : true,
        cwd : 'radio/static/css/',
        src : [ '*.styl' ],
        ext : [ '.css' ]
    } ];

    var stylusRadioLightFiles = [ {
        expand : true,
        cwd : 'radio/static/polymer/radio-light/',
        src : [ '**/*.styl' ],
        ext : [ '.css' ]
    } ];

    var stylusthemesFiles = [ {
        expand : true,
        cwd : 'radio/static/themes/',
        src : [ '**/*.styl' ],
        ext : [ '.css' ]
    } ];
```

In your stylus

```
         stylus: {
         stylusStaticFiles: {
                    files: stylusStaticFiles,
                },
                stylusRadioLightFiles: {
                    files: stylusRadioLightFiles,
                },
                stylusthemesFiles: {
                    files: stylusthemesFiles,
                }
     }
```

In the watch

```
    watch: {
            stylusStaticFiles: {
                files: ['radio/static/css/*.styl'],
                tasks: ['stylus:stylusStaticFiles']
            },

             stylusRadioLightFiles: {
                files: ['radio/static/themes/**/*.styl'],
                tasks: ['stylus:stylusRadioLightFiles']
            },
            stylusthemesFiles: {
                files: ['radio/static/polymer/radio-light/**/*.styl'],
                tasks: ['stylus:stylusthemesFiles']
            }
  }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This solution leads to recompilation of all files, matched each pattern, e.g. if only one file among static files changed this will make stylus to recompile each file matched static files pattern.

Comment: This is not bad, because I'll concat all css files in production, this means all my .STYL files would be compiled to only one CSS file eventually. But in development I want to have separate CSS files (because some of the them are parts of Polymer Elements), so I have another solution, it is more suitable in particular case, but useless in production. I'll update my question in few minutes.